# Как менять порядок вывода баннеров для отдельных разделов сайта (Битрикс)?

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Есть сайт на битриксе. В шаблоне сайта подключается вывод баннеров по порядку

```
<? $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:advertising.banner", 
    "right", 
    array(
        "TYPE" => "RIGHT_ACT1",
        "NOINDEX" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "N",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000"
        ),
    false
    );
?>
```

и т.д.

Необходимо для некоторых разделов каталога поменять порядок вывода баннеров. Я попробовала через $APPLICATION->GetCurPage(), но это не сработало.

```
<?if($APPLICATION->GetCurPage() == "#/catalog/avto/#i || 
                                    #/catalog/med/#i || 
                                    #/catalog/tov/#i || 
                                    #/catalog/const/#i || 
                                    #/catalog/doma/#i ||
                                    #/catalog/hozyaystvo/#i"){
   *вывод баннеров в нужном порядке*
}?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как поменять порядок вывода баннеров для отдельных разделов сайта?